# Best way to send data client server

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, client

What is the best way to handle data that needs to get send to the server? I have an multi thread client, in all threads there is data that needs to get send to the server. But when I launch the server there are some times packets that are send at the same time. So the data is not correct at that time.

I thought, lets make a stack that gets send to the server every x ms. Is this a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use message queue structure. There will only one queue in the server and every time a message arrives at the queue its added to the end of the queue, therefore even the messages are sent at the same time  they will be ordered. After that process the message in the queue by dequeuing the messages. There are many open source message queue structures you can use, so you do not have to implement it from scratch.
You do not have to wait x seconds to send the data to the server in this structure. This will make your system faster.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Open one socket per client-thread. That way the server can separate from which thread it comes from and everything is kept in order.

Comment: I already have that, but the problem is that the client multi threaded is. So it will send multi lines at once.

Comment: But every thread only sends one line at a time, so if you keep the sockets separate, then you have everything in order. Am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I read your answer wrong. You are ride. That is indeed possible. But is it no easier to use 1 socket for a client?